# swiftui - NavigationSplitView Crashes in Landscape Mode on iPad (iOS 16.2)

Tags: swiftui, crash, navigationsplitview

i am working on an app for iphone and ipad and wanted to use NavigationSplitView.
When running on an iPad in landscape orientation i am running into a crash on iOS 16.2 that i can't really understand.

In this example you can reproduce the crash on iPad in landscaope mode like this: First select "George" and then click on his book "Big Book" (last in the list for him). Then select "Luca". Click on his first book entry ("Boring book"). At this point this crashes the whole app. I get an

Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x105c9fe94)

(of course no breakpoint has been set).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

KB

This is the code (you can paste it directly into a new project):

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  test
//


import SwiftUI

struct Member:Hashable, Identifiable {
var id: Int
var name: String
    
}

struct Book:Hashable, Identifiable {
var id: Int
var memberId: Int
var name: String
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var memberID: Member.ID? // Single selection.
    @State private var bookID: Book.ID? // Single selection.
    @State private var columnVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all
    
    
    
    var members = [
        Member(id:1, name:"George"),
        Member(id:2, name:"John"),
        Member(id:3, name:"Luca"),
    ]
    
    
    var books
    = [
        Book(id:1,memberId:1, name:"A good Book"),
        Book(id:2, memberId:1, name:"Another great Book"),
        Book(id:3, memberId: 1, name:"Very good Book"),
        Book(id:4,memberId:1, name:"Lame Book"),
        Book(id:5, memberId:1, name:"Big Book"),
        Book(id:6, memberId: 2, name:"Small Book"),
        Book(id:7,memberId:2, name:"Green Book"),
        Book(id:8, memberId:2, name:"Yellow Book"),
        Book(id:9, memberId: 3, name:"Boring Book"),
        Book(id:10, memberId: 3, name:"Best Book"),
    ]
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            List(members, selection: $memberID) { member in
                HStack{
                    Text("ID: \(member.id)")
                    Text("Name: \(member.name)")
                }
                
            } //List
            
        } content: {
            
            if memberID == nil {
                Text("select")
                
            } else {
                List(books.filter({ $0.memberId == memberID }), selection: $bookID) { book in
                    
                    
                    Text(book.name)
                    
                } //List
                
            } //else
            
            
        } detail: {
            
            Text("Details")
        }// detail
        .onChange(of: memberID){ _ in
            bookID = nil
        }
        
    } // body
    
    
    
    
}
```

It seems to have something to do with the list of member 1 being longer than that of member 3. The values of member 3 are ok and can be selected if you go there directly.

I followed the developer documentation and various tutorials. I searched on SO but haven't found this specific problem. I am probably missing something.